# how to customize tools in ckeditor and also display the customize tools

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CK Editor in my project. My requirement are image upload, source editor, font styles etc and make size of the CK_Editor ADJUSTABLE

To display the editor in web page, I have searched Google and I have got something like

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.removePlugins = 'forms';

};
```

but it doesn't work. kindly help me on this. Please provide step
by step solution.

I will be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

First download latest version of ck editor and then add below lines in config.js

```
config.extraPlugins = 'filebrowser';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'Baseurl/controller_name/ckeditorImageUpload';
```

add below function to your desired controller

```
/**
 *
 * This function used to upload images from ckeditor
 */
public function ckeditorImageUpload(){
        $time = time();

        //echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];exit;
        //$url = '../../uploads/'.$time."_".$_FILES['upload']['name'];

        $url = './images/ckeditor/uploads/' . $time . "_" . $_FILES['upload']['name'];

        $furl = 'http' . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $fdata = explode('ckupload.php', $furl);

        //extensive suitability check before doing anything with the file...
        if (($_FILES['upload'] == "none") OR (empty($_FILES['upload']['name']))) {
            $message = "No file uploaded.";
        } else if ($_FILES['upload']["size"] == 0) {
            $message = "The file is of zero length.";
        } else if (($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/pjpeg") AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/jpeg") AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/png")) {
            $message = "The image must be in either JPG or PNG format. Please upload a JPG or PNG instead.";
        } else if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']["tmp_name"])) {
            $message = "You may be attempting to hack our server. We're on to you; expect a knock on the door sometime soon.";
        } else {
            $message = "";
            echo $url;
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($fdata);
            //exit;
            $move = @ move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $url);
            if (!$move) {
                $message = "Error moving uploaded file. Check the script is granted Read/Write/Modify permissions.";
            }
            //$url = $fdata[0]."uploads/" . $time."_".$_FILES['upload']['name'];
            $url = base_url() . "images/ckeditor/uploads/" . $time . "_" . $_FILES['upload']['name'];
        }

        $CKEditorFuncNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'];
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url', '$message');</script>";



}
```

Comment: i'm trying to customize the tools in editor ...not only, the image uploading part...i need to remove the cut,paste,copy, undu, redo buttons  and someother buttons from the viewing area...please help...

Answer (score 0):

In your config.js file paste below code:

```
config.toolbar = 'Full';
config.toolbar_Full =
    [
        { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
        { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'] },
        { name: 'forms', items: ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
            'HiddenField'] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv',
            '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl'] },
        { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
        { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe'] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
        { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] }
        ,{ name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', 'About'] }
    ];
```

And if you want to remove cut,copy and paste button then remove or comment below line, Do same for other buttons.

```
{ name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
```